# Old code keeps executing instead of BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, sockets, beautifulsoup

I've been working with Python for Everybody and there came a time I had to use a socket to pull info out of a browser, using this code:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd= 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data= mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print (data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

However, moving on to using BeautifulSoup I found everytime I tried a code with bs it would completely ignore it and pull out the results for romeo.txt. But if I use bs in command prompt, line by line, it works perfectly.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm'
>>> req= requests.get(url)
>>> soup= BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
>>> print (soup.title)
<title>RxJS, ggplot2, Python Data Persistence, Caffe2, PyBrain, Python Data Access, H2O, Colab, Theano, Flutter, KNime, Mean.js, Weka, Solidity</title>
```

Though as soon as I call the file, it's romeo.txt again, command freezes and I have to close it:

```
C:\Users\nnll\Desktop\pythonfiles>bs.py
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 26 Jul 2020 21:35:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 May 2017 11:22:22 GMT
ETag: "a7-54f6609245537"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 167
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

This is what appears if I use `type bs.py`:

```
C:\Users\nnll\Desktop\pythonfiles>type bs.py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm'
req= requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
print (soup.title)
```

Comment: Type this at the command line: `type bs.py`.  Are you now sure that the source code file you are running is actually the code you think it is?  Otherwise, post the entire `bs.py` file here in your question.

Comment: 'Old socket keeps opening' is meaningless Do you mean old *data* being received? Old *code* being executed? Please clarify.

Comment: If you've got a `bs.pyc` file, delete it.